# How to call SQL Agent Job Wizard from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, ssms, jobs, wizard

I need it to automate modification of SQL Server Scheduled jobs and want to reuse functionality of SSMS Scheduled job wizard.

Is it possible to popup SSMS Scheduled job wizard using PowerShell, use it and then close?

**Update**: I am aware of how to modify jobs using SPs and PS. The wizard is just one step in automated process. The next steps are to read the job settings and generate job script as per company's standard (that is important as out of the box Drop and Create script is not good enough), set encoding of the file etc.

Comment: `automate` and `wizard` in the same sentence is like an oxymoron, everything you do in the scheduled job wizard can be done with SQL commands which can be executed from PowerShell.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I've added clarification on what I need to automate in the update. Hope that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You call a job via integrated MS SQL procedure [sp_start_job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx). You call this SQL via [Invoke-SqlCmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx).

To modify/create the job you have to use `sp_add_job`, `sp_add_jobstep`, `sp_update_job` and `sp_add_jobschedule`.